# Can't see changes outside Hibernate session after flushing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, flush

I'm using `Spring 3.1.2` with `Hibernate 4`.

I have a DAO implementation class `MyDaoImpl` annotated with `@Repository` so that exception translation is enabled. I have a service class `MyService` annotated with `@Transactional` as follows:

```
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
       this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveA(A a)
    {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(a);
    }
}
```

I've wrote a unit tests class `MyDaoImplTest` as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:beans.xml" })
@Transactional
public class MyDaoImplTest implements IMyDaoImplTest {

    private MyDao myDao;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setMyDao(MyDao myDao)
    {
        this.myDao = myDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Test
    @Override
    public void testCreateA()
    {
       A a = new A("A1");
       this.myDao.saveA(a);

       this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();

       IDataSet databaseDataSet = this.getConnection().createDataSet();
       ITable actualTable = databaseDataSet.getTable("Applications");

   IDataSet expectedDataSet = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder().build(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test-data/applications/savenew.xml"));
   ITable expectedTable = expectedDataSet.getTable("Applications");

   Assertion.assertEquals(expectedTable, actualTable);
    }
}
```

According to the Spring documentation, I flush the session after my changes in order to avoid false positives. The problem is that after flushing, if I access the DB outside Hibernate (e.g. using DBUnit), I can't see the changes, so my asserts always fail.

What is wrong with my config?

Answer (score 3):

That is expected behavior. Flush is different concept from transaction commit. You can see changes outside of transaction only after commit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, what's wrong with the way I test my DAO? By doing this way, I can't see the changes, so I can't test my DAO.

Comment: Your test will need to retrieve the data within the same session/transaction.

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout How to use DBUnit within the same session/transaction? DBUnit communicates directly with the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the state of the database after transaction commit, you have two options:

- Do the check in a method annotated with `@AfterTransaction`. This method will be executed by Spring JUnit runner after the end of transaction defined by `@Tranactional` test method. Don't forget to disable automatic transaction rollback `(@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)`). If you need different check for different test methods, you can do something like this:

  ```
  private Runnable check;

  @AfterTransaction
  public void performCheck() {
      if (check != null) check.run();
  }

  @Test
  @Override
  public void testCreateA() {
      ... // Code being tested
      check = new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              ... // Code to check the state
          }
      };
  }
  ```
- Use programmatic transaction demarcation inside the test method:

  ```
  private TransactionTemplate tx;

  @Autowired
  private void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager ptm) {
      tx = new TransactionTemplate(ptm);
  }

  @Test
  @Override
  @Transactional(progrgation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED) // Disable declarative transaction
  public void testCreateA() {
      tx.execute(...); // Code to test
      tx.execute(...); // Check
  }
  ```

Alternatively, if your goal is to use DbUnit to check results of Hibernate flush, you can do it in the same transaction, for example, using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().doWork(...)`.